# Stuck on splash screen, after changing /usr/lib/ directory permission

Tags: 18.04

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 64bit.

Inorder to run the twine_2.3.5_linux64 file I made one permission change in /usr/lib/ directory.

```
sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/lib/
```

After a restart, it stuck on the splash screen, not getting tty also.

Pls, help.

Comment: Some programs/services require file to have a specific permission otherwise they'll refuse to run (a wrong permission could mean a hack..).  Many permissions in my /usr/lib/ do **not** have 644 as permissions, so I'd suggest restoring permissions back the way they were... (restoring backup, or whatever you did to allow reversal of your `chmod`)

Comment: This seems not solves your problem. but chmod have literal way of setting permissions like `u+Xrw,g+Xrw,o+r`, or `u=Xrw,g=Xrw,o=` - the main thing is X - setting x attribute to folders and leave executable if file already have it

Comment: Try to run `sudo chmod -R u+Xrw,g+Xr,o+Xr /usr/lib/` from live cd, I think this could help

Answer (score 0):

Try using live CD. Here you can solve the issue using terminal by changing permissions of folder to 755.

Comment: Ok...let me try

Comment: after applying chmod -R 755 /usr/lib on live showing : 'chmod changing permissions of ...... no space left on device'

Comment: Sorry I am not sure about your problem. This may help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671621/no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: thanks.. changing permission 755 done successfully (previosly faced some mounting issue)... now its working fine